# Conditional saving of field_for data in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have a rails app that has a customer model and and address model.  The customer can have many addresses.  I've created a form that uses field_for so users can enter both the customer details and an address on the same form.
Heres the models

customer.rb

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :addresses, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
end
```

address.rb

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :customer

  validates :atype, presence: true


  ADDRESSTYPE = %w(Billing Delivery Postal)
    validates :atype, inclusion: { in: ADDRESSTYPE }
end
```

And here's the form.

```
<%= form_with(model: customer, local: true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :firstname %>
  <%= f.text_field :firstname %>
  <%= f.label :surname %>
  <%= f.text_field :surname %>
  <%= f.label :location %>
  <%= f.text_field :location %>
  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email %>
  <%= f.label :mobile_number %>
  <%= f.text_field :mobile_number %>
  <%= f.label :company %>
  <%= f.text_field :company_name_legacy %>
  <%= f.fields_for :addresses do |address| %>
        <%= address.label :address_type %>
        <%= address.select :atype, Address::ADDRESSTYPE %>
        <%= address.label :address_line_1 %>
        <%= address.text_field :line_1 %>
        <%= address.label :address_line_2 %>
        <%= address.text_field :line_2 %>
        <%= address.label :city %>
        <%= address.text_field :city %>
        <%= address.label :state %>
        <%= address.text_field :state %>
        <%= address.label :postcode %>
        <%= address.text_field :postcode %>
        <%= address.label :country %>
        <%= address.text_field :country %>     
   <% end %> 
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

My controller for saving the new customer is as follows,

```
def new
        @customer = Customer.new
        @customer.addresses.build
    end

    def create
        @customer = Customer.new customer_params
        @customer.save

        redirect_to @customer
    end
```

I'd like to be able to prevent the address from being saved if Line_1 of the address is empty.  I can't figure out how to test to see if it's empty, or how to prevent it being saved as part of saving the customer? Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While @Yakov's answer is technically correct, it will show a validation error and this is sometimes not desired.

If you want to save the Customer even without an Addres, you can add a callback to the Customer modal like so:

```
before_save :mark_addresses_for_removal

def mark_addresses_for_removal
  addresses.each do |address|
    address.mark_for_destruction unless address.address_line_1?
  end
end
```

This will also cause the address to be removed when editing a Customer if the address_line_1 text is cleared.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I was looking for.
A slight correction for my model - the test is address.line_1?
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can add validation to `Address` model `validates :atype, :line_1, presence: true` then rewrite `create` method like this:

```rb
def create
  @customer = Customer.new customer_params
  if @customer.save
    redirect_to @customer
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

And add a little piece of code to display errors at the top of your form:

```
<% if @customer.errors.any? %>
  <ul>
    <% @customer.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
      <li><%= message %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Also, fields with triggered validations will have wrapped `div` element with class `field_with_errors`. You can add CSS styles to highlight fields with errors.